# grab file from url issue

Tags: php, file

i want to grab file from url using (file_put_contents) function but i can't and i got error (file not found) but i am sure 100% the path of the file is correct because when i clicked on the link for download the file in the same site it works but when i want to grab it it says not found.

see this path

http://bramegm.com/software/files/soft53/ElaSalaty.exe

when you try to grab it or also try to use (linux command like wget) you got that the file is not found but see the file page

http://www.bramegm.com/software/download/elasalaty/%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%8A

go to the bottom and you will see the same file path click on it and it will downloaded.

any help to grab this file without entering the site.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to download the file from `http://bramegm.com/software/files/soft53/ElaSalaty.exe` but in the given URL i see the actual link is `http://www.bramegm.com/software/files/soft54/ElaSalaty.exe`. Please notice the difference in **soft53** and **soft54**.